# How do we prove locally finite closed covers are identification covers?

Tags: general-topology

Discription: I am trying to understand a portion of the proof, following, that locally finite closed covers are identification covers in Manetti's Topology book. I am lost on how U is known to be open in X with the given assumptions, so I was wondering if someone could describe the author's reasoning onto why this is true or guide me to an alternative proof method.

Definition: Identification Cover - $U \subset X$ is open if and only if $U \cap A$ is open in A for every A $\in \mathcal A$.

Proof:
If $\{C_{i} | i \in I\}$ is a locally finite, closed cover of X, we can find an open cover $\mathcal A$ in such a way that $\{C_{i} \cap A | i \in I\}$ is a closed, finite cover of A, for any A $\in \mathcal A$. Therefore, if $U \cap C_{i}$ is open in $C_{i}$ for every i, $U \cap C_{i} \cap A$ is open in $A \cap C_{i}$ for all A $\in \mathcal A$, and then $U \cap A$ is open in A for all A $\in \mathcal A$. The conclusion is that U is open in X.

Note: Thank you in advance. Have a nice day.

Comment: What is your identification covers 's definition?

Comment: If, for a subset U, U is open only if its intersection with A is open for each A in *A*, a cover of X. The definition is also posted in this post. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the fact that a union of a locally finite family of closed sets is closed and use the closed-set characterisation of an identification cover $\{C_i\mid i \in I\}$:

$A$ is closed iff $A \cap C_i$ is closed in $C_i$ for each $i$.